# Gradle project sync failed basic functionality will not work

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to start android programming with android studio IDE but when I install android studio i am getting this error "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g editing , debugging) will notwork properly".

Please someone guide me to solve this error keeping in mind that I am very beginner.

Comment: Can you post your Gradle file?

Comment: as I mentioned i just start with android studio therefore i don't know what the Gradle is and how to find it's file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your build.gradle (Module:app), if you have a "compile" task with a version like 25+, you have to change it for a version like 25.1.0.

In that case you would see this warning message: "Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds".